# Scheduling cloud tasks far in the future

Tags: google-cloud-tasks

I am using the Python Client for Cloud Tasks API to schedule tasks in the future (the handler is running as an AppEngine Flex service).

When scheduling tasks in the future, what is the limit for `Task.schedule_time`, i.e., how far in the future can I schedule a task?

(The documentation mentions a task retention of 30 days, but it does not specify whether that applies only to failed tasks or it also implies a hard limit for future scheduling).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum time the task can be scheduled in the future is 30 days. The task's retention time in the queue is 31 days after creation.

[Quotas & Limits](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/quotas) has been updated to reflect this.